# Chaining multiple async functions where one depends on another in Javascript/ Nodejs, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have two functions that depend on each other. After my user saves his profile, I first have a function that saves his location and then returns its id, which I then use to update the user. But after trying a lot of combinations I couldn't get it to work properly. I'll list below what I tried.

```
async function NewUserProfileUpdate(req) {
    try {
        const loc_id = LocationController.AddUserLocation(req.body.location.longitude
            , req.body.location.latitude, req.query.id)

        loc_id.then((id) => {
            logger.info("Then " + id)
            UserModel.User.updateOne({ user_id: req.query.id }, {
                gender: req.body.gender, name: req.body.name, bio: req.body.bio,
                location_id: id
            })
        })

    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

```
async function AddUserLocation(longitude, latitude, userID) {
    const location = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [longitude, latitude] }

    await LocationModel.create(
        { user_id: userID, location: location }, function (err, loc) {
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }
            logger.info("Created + " + loc._id)
            return loc._id
        });
}
```

Then is called before create

```
info: Then undefined {"service":"user-service"}
info: Created + 5feb3174f70c08f9543fdc49 {"service":"user-service"}
```

I tried using events, chaining it with then =>, chaining with asyncs (idk why this doesnt work, I had async for loc_id, and that should wait until loc_id returns but it doesnt), I tried different combinations of regular functions and asyncs but nothing gave me the desired result. (I have gotten a result using async and events but without listeners, I have no idea what happened there)

Comment: async/await has to be consistent from start to end. Both below answers are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `async`/`await`, you should not use `.then()` and must not pass callbacks to mongoose methods so that they return `await`able promises.

```
async function NewUserProfileUpdate(req) {
    const location_id = await LocationController.AddUserLocation(req.body.location, req.query.id);
//                      ^^^^^
    logger.info("Then " + location_id);

    await UserModel.User.updateOne({ user_id: req.query.id }, {
//  ^^^^^
        gender: req.body.gender,
        name: req.body.name,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        location_id,
    });
}

async function AddUserLocation({longitude, latitude}, user_id) {
    const location = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [longitude, latitude] };

    const loc = await LocationModel.create({ user_id, location });
//                                                              ^ no callback
    logger.info("Created + " + loc._id);

    return loc._id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const loc_id = await LocationController.AddUserLocation(req.body.location.longitude
            , req.body.location.latitude, req.query.id)
```

I believe this should solve the issue. Since you are not waiting for the response from AddUserLocation therefore the control moves on and executes then().